# htaccess add index.htm at end of folder

Tags: .htaccess

I need a way to add index.htm at end of url.
For example:
www.example.com/folder1/folder2 AND 
www.example.com/folder1/folder2/
must be redirected internally to www.example.com/folder1/folder2/index.htm (this must apply for any number of folders/subfolders)

My htaccess (at root) so far looks like:

> ```
> Options +FollowSymLinks
> RewriteEngine on
> RewriteOptions inherit
> RewriteBase /
>
> #
> # some 301 REDIRECTS here
> #
>
>
> # rewrite non-www into www
> # after all redirection rule AND before any rewrite rule
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
>
>
>
> #
> # rewrite rules below here
> #
> ```

Any way to fix this?
Thank you.

**EDIT:**
 - All urls come from rewrite rules - there are no actual folders in site.
 - Typing www.example.com/folder1/folder2 in my browser,  only get a 404 page not found. I need it to redirect to www.example.com/folder1/folder2/index.htm (there is a rule creating this url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.htm$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1/index.htm [L,R=301]
```

Comment: For somereason this don't work. I tied putting it on top of htaccess and tried putting it after RewriteBase /. Never worked (in both cases).

If i type www.example.com/folder1/folder2 in my browser i just get a 404 error

Comment: That is strange. Is mod_dir enabled in your httpd.conf?

Comment: Just saw this: `there are no actual folders in site` so `/folder1/folder2` is not a real folder?

Comment: correct. All of the project is based on rewrite rules, without actual physical folders present. The worst scenario i can think of is to write 100+ 3001 redirection rules, but i look for a way to avoid this.

Comment: I am a bit confused. If `/folder1/folder2` is not a real folder then how can there be a `/folder1/folder2/index.html`?

Comment: RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/index.htm$ path/to/file.php?var1=$1&var2=$2 [NC,L]

Comment: So do you just want to always show `index.htm` in your URL? If yes then may I ask why?

Comment: the site is an old static one. Some links had /index.htm on them, some did not. Owner wants to always has extension .htm on his pages since we are rebuilding it.

Comment: its closer to solution but not 100% correct. It adds /index.htm to all urls. And if url ends in trailing slash, it adds another. So, with the current solution i now get urls like: /folder1/folder2//index.htm and /folder1/folder2/index.htm/index.htm

Comment: Made an edit, pls check. Double slash is harmless but anyway I took care of it. However can't understand how can it make double `index.htm` since I already had a condition: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index\.htm$ [NC]`

Comment: ok for the double slash. It is not only double index.htm. If my url ends in page.htm, now i get page.htm/index.htm. I thought that the RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f took care not to interfere with all files. Perhaps i must place this rule to some specific place to operate 100% correct?

Comment: Ok made another edit to take care of `page.htm/index.htm` issue. Now if a URI is ending with `.htm` then `/index.htm` will not be appended.

Comment: anubhava ok this seems to work 100% correct. I moved rule to end of htaccess also and i have not observed any weird behaviour so far

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to REDIRECT `/folder1` and `/folder1/` into `/folder1/index.htm`, and `/folder1/folder2` and `/folder1/folder2/` to `/folder1/folder2/index.htm`, and `/folder1/folder2/folder3` and `/folder1/folder2/folder3/` to `/folder1/folder2/folder3/index.htm`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([a-z0-9-_]+)/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*) /%1/index.htm [R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([a-z0-9-_]+)/([a-z0-9-_]+)/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*) /%1/%2/index.htm [R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([a-z0-9-_]+)/([a-z0-9-_]+)/([a-z0-9-_]+)/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*) /%1/%2/%3/index.htm [R]
```